# Why is a selection sort faster than this custom sort?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Why is selectionSort faster than customSort? It seems that customSort moves values around more than it has to. However, selectionSort has far more variable assignments, which I'm not sure how factor into speed.

```
void selectionSort(int array[], int size)
{
    int startScan, minIndex, minValue;
    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = array[startScan];
        for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
        {
            if (array[index] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = array[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
        array[startScan] = minValue;
    }
}

void customSort(int a[],int n){
    for(int j=0;j<n-1;j++){
        for(int i=j+1;i<n;i++){
            if(a[j]>a[i]){
                a[j]=a[j]^a[i];
                a[i]=a[j]^a[i];
                a[j]=a[j]^a[i];
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: You are performing six operations (XOR and assignment) inside the innermost `customSort` loop if items need swapping (potentially `6*size*size/2` times). selection sort performs four assignments in the outmost loop and two in the innermost loop (`size*(4+2*size/2)`). It takes an input that barely needs sorting to make `customSort` require less operations.

Comment: @TinyT In those expressions, why do you divide by 2? Is it because of the 2 loops?

Comment: it is because your starting index in the inner loop depends on the current index in the outer loop. if you draw a square (one row for each iteration of the outside loop = `size` rows and `size` columns) and then mark those that you examine, you will find that you go through less and less columns - in fact, the marked cells form a triangle that has roughly half the area of the square. So you have half the amount of iterations. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both algorithms do O(n^2) comparisons.  customSort does O(n^2) swaps while selectionSort does O(n) swaps.  But that only tells you about the relative performance as n goes to infinity.  How long this actually takes depends on the optimizer, the processor, and the cache and memory speeds.  It can go either way, especially when n is "small."

The only way to know which will actually be faster is to measure.  It's not a matter of how to think about the problem.

Given that you've already determined that selectionSort is faster in your case, we could come up with some hypotheses.

Since selectionSort needs only two extra values, it's quite probable that the optimizer arranged to keep them in registers.  It also is very cache friendly in that almost all the memory reads are sequential.

Compare to customSort, which has to read two values from memory.  The swapping happens more often and requires at least two stores to memory.

If storing to memory is slower than storing to a register (which is probable), then it's not surprising that the selectionSort is faster, even though it customSort uses a trick to avoid the need for temporary variables.

Comment: Why does customSort have to read values from memory? Also, at least how many stores to memory does selectionSort require and why?

Comment: Also, what is the difference between a swap and a variable assignment?

Comment: Sorry, I was interrupted while editing, so the wording is a bit sloppy.  I'll try to improve it today.  To do the comparison, selectionSort reads one value from the array and compares it to the min-so-far, which is likely in a register.  The customSort must almost certainly read two values from memory for each comparison.  The swap in customSort must commit both values to memory, but the variable assignments in selectionSort are to variables that are likely in registers and don't need to be written to memory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TinyT, I realized that the speed of the algorithm depends on the amount of potential operations that algorithm might perform.

Per @TinyT's suggestion, I drew out a simple use case for both of these algos, and determined that customSort has the potential to perform more operations than selectionSort, given the same array size.

@TinyT also provided approximations for the potential number of operations of each algorithm, which make sense if you refer to his comment on my question, and note the triangle pattern in the assignment of i with respect to j.

As a side note - in my drawing I used the variables i and j with selectionSort for convenience rather than accuracy with respect to the actual variable names. Also, in the drawing, the size used in the approximations is the size of the loop iterations.

[image: drawing]